# Regex with numbers and special characters but no letters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm making a regex that accepts an input with any decimal(0-9), +, * or # but shouldn't accept any letters(a-z).

so numbers like

- #192#
- *31#+32475728966
- 0479266315
- +32495959511

should be accepted.

The regex is invalid when there is any letter in the string.

- #192#abbef
- a0479266315

This is the regex I have so far:

```
private const string PhoneNumberRegex = "((\\d)|(\\*)|(\\#)|(\\+))?";

private bool IsValid(inputString)
{
    // Accept * # + and number
    Match match = Regex.Match(inputString, PhoneNumberRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return match.Success;
}
```

But this regex also returns true on #192#abbef

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this:

```
private const string PhoneNumberRegex = @"^[0-9*#+]+$";
```

Where `^` and `$` are anchors for start and end of the string.

Note: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to anchor your string with `^` (begin of line) and `$` (end of line). Otherwise your string matches if *any* part of it matches.

Also, you want at least one of those characters (you don't want to match an empty string, so you should use `+` (one or more).

Lastly, you can make a character class out of all your characters: `[\d*#+]`.

Putting it all together gives you:

```
private const string PhoneNumberRegex = "^[\\d*#+]+$";
```

This means that from the beginning of the string till the end, you want one or more of those characters you listed.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a lot of regex experience so your explanation is very usefull.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will meet your needs

```
private const string PhoneNumberRegex = @"^([0-9]|#|\+|\*)+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
const string MYRegex = @"^[0-9*#+]+$";
```

for more information plz visit

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=special%20characters&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios_xr_sw/iosxr_r3.4/getting_started/installation/guide/gs34aexp.pdf